# How to move files between Document Types in Documents and Media Portlet Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

I want to know can we move the files in the Documents and Media between Documents Type.

Eg.

I have uploaded a file **demo.pdf** in Basic Documents. Now I want to move the **demo.pdf** to Contract Document Type.

How to achieve the above.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** ***`move`*** files to a different Document Type, but you can **`edit`** each file individually to move them to a particular Document Type.

Think of Document-type as field for a file like title, description etc, albeit a special one. Document types are not folders.

Or else you can write code to change the Document-type for more that one file, but that would be quite an effort.